# Typescript define an array of objects that must have id: number as one of its attributes

Tags: typescript

I want to allow an arrays of objects of any shape, as long as they have `id: number` present.

So whether it is an array of `OrderModel` or `UserModel` (both of which have `id: number`), how can I define such an array?

export interface Item {
id: number;
// whatever else, doesn't matter
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the fact that arrays are [covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covariance-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc), just define `Item` as:

```
interface Item {
  id: number;
}
```

Then let say you have the following types:

```
interface OrderModel {
  id: number;
  type: "order";
  // other props
}

interface UserModel {
  id: number;
  type: "user";
  // other props
}
```

The following will be allowed:

```
declare const os: Array<OrderModel>;
declare const us: Array<UserModel>;

declare function doStuff(xs: Array<Item>): unknown;

doStuff(os);
doStuff(us);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLbIN4ChnLAAmAXMiAK4YBG0A3LgL766iSyIoDyUR0AsgHs+AGxz5CpclVpQGBMAE8ADhDIAiQb2jr5yAPT7kgsAAtoyZVEHKAzk1ytw0eEmQBVWwOEQxeAsRklDT0EkqqGhReULoShsZmFlY29sy4fAgicFAoCIIgtmDGtmQAglBQcIoAPDx8UEKiAHwMGVk5yHkFRVFlFVXVnt7NDOkQmdkoMBQgCGDA+chEggDKYBQwMAAUAB4lyOWVNegQGE0AlGQAboLEo8trG9uCtuetq+ubW1FvQA)